# T4 assembly directive broken in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: t4, visual-studio-2017

I have a design-time T4 template which has worked for years in VS2013 and VS2015.

In VS2017, the template fails to run with a MissingMethodException. The method in question is housed within a custom assembly. The assembly is referenced using an absolute path along with the $(SolutionDir) macro. Something like:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)path\my.dll"#>
```

I've been using the Fusion Log Viewer to debug this issue. Apparently, "my.dll" cannot be found. And according to the logs, Visual Studio isn't looking in the absolute path.

I assume this is a bug within the T4VSHost. Is there anyway to fix this or workaround it?

Comment: As a workaround, I'm placing my.dll in the "my" sub-directory of $(DevEnvDir). Personally, I think this is a bad practice. But Fusion will find it this way. I'd prefer to place it somewhere more responsible and instruct Fusion where to find it.

Comment: Can hard-coding file path work?

Comment: @qxg, are you suggesting there's something wrong with the macro (or the macro expansion)? Apparently, that's not the issue. I hard-coded the path to test the theory - no go.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio, in 2017 and prior,  will hold a lock on assemblies it has built in the current VS session.  So if your path looks something like.

`<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)SomeProjectFolder\bin\Debug\SomeAssembly.dll" #>`

Then the T4 engine will throw an exception saying the Assembly cannot be found.  If you resart the solution and then run the T4 template without building, it will run correctly.

This makes debugging or otherwise working on assemblies that are primarily intended for reference in T4 templates, a pain.